# JsonResult not returning (valid) json - Serializing going wrong?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

I try to make a simple call to a server-side method in ASP.NET MVC 4. I do this by making a jQuery call to a method. The method gets called and the properties are correct, but the response of this method is not correct. I try to serialize an .NET object using JSON.NET.

I can see I get the following response (using FireBug):

```
"{\"VisitorId\":\"11a0606b-5336-4fa7-b50f-3edf97d8301b\",\"PhoneToTransfer\":\"61793650\",\"PhoneToNotify\":\"\",\"EmailToNotify\":\"mcoroklo@gmail.com\",\"EmailToTransfer\":\"\",\"OrderState\":\"PaymentPending\",\"DestinationAddress\":\"1Ccypfi3rnXosUgY6p1sQVXFyddFvwLFEJ\",\"TransactionHash\":\"\",\"Value\":12.0,\"Confirmations\":-1,\"TransactionDate\":\"2013-01-09T22:36:33.7991116+01:00\"}"
```

This doesn't parse as correct JSON, and I have no idea why. Also, the "JSON" tab in Firebug says "There are no properties to show for this object".

I am pretty sure my content-type and dataType is correct on the call.

This is my code to make the JSON - using The JSON.NET library:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult StartPurchase(string phoneReceiver, string emailNotify, string value)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        BlockchainPayments block = new BlockchainPayments();
        var address = block.GetAddress(BtcContext.PurchaseSession);

        decimal val = 0;
        decimal.TryParse(value, out val);

        var ps = new PurchaseService();
        var purchase = ps.StartPurchase(BtcContext.PurchaseSession, phoneReceiver, emailNotify, address.destination, val);
        return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(purchase));
    }
    return Json("Error");
}
```

This is the jQuery call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: dataToSend,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Awesome destination succes');
    },
    error: function (date) {
        alert('An occurred while purchasing. Please try again later');
    }
});
```

Any idea why it's not returning valid JSON? And any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are double encoding it, just use one conversion method, e.g. `return Json(purchase);`

Comment: *Stackoverflow highfive* - solved the problem.. Now, off to bed and get some fresh eyes.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`return Json` already serializes an object I believe. Looks like you're getting double serialization.